# not able to fetch data from subscribed topic from test.mosquitto.org

Tags: esp8266

here is my lua script ,running on esp8266 with nodemcu firmware,I am keeping a function check_wifi() to check that my esp module is connected ,then I am publishing topic "on" , and setting two event handler for "connect" and for "message",but my handler for

```
  function check_wifi()
     local ip = wifi.sta.getip()
     if(ip==nil) then
       print("Connecting...")
     else
      tmr.stop(0)
      print("Connected to AP!")
      print(ip)

      m:connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883, 0, function(conn) print("connected") end)
      m:publish("on","1",0,0,0)
      m:on("connect",function(m) 

        m:subscribe("on",0,function(m) print(m);print("subcribed") end)

        end )
       m:on("message", function(conn, topic, data)
    print("in on")
      print(topic .. ":" )
      if data ~= nil then
        print(data)
      end
    end)
    end
    end

    local SSID = "Crystalrock2"
    local SSID_PASSWORD = "nest2abc123"

    gpio.mode(4,gpio.OUTPUT)
    gpio.write(4,gpio.LOW)

    -- configure ESP as a station
    wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
    wifi.sta.config(SSID,SSID_PASSWORD)
    wifi.sta.connect()

    m = mqtt.Client("dee15", 120, "test", "password")

    m:on("message", function(conn, topic, data)
    print("in on")
      print(topic .. ":" )
      if data ~= nil then
        print(data)
      end
    end)

    m:on("connect",function(m) 

        m:subscribe("on",0,function(m) print(m);print("subcribed") end)

        end )
    m:connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883, 0, function(conn) print("connected") end)


    tmr.alarm(0,2000,1,check_wifi)
```

here what I am getting:
output:Connecting...
Connecting...
Connected to AP!
192.168.0.100
userdata: 3fff8678
subcribed

why m:on("message" ..)is not triggering and printing message received

Comment: Your code is a mess. All `m:on` event handlers are defined twice (in- & outside `check_wifi()`). You re-use and overwrite the `m` variable. Analyze what which `m` you have on line 13 (`m:subscribe`).

Comment: Thanks ,I solved the problem by synchronizing all my functionality using timers.